# Beginner in mathematics, i'm studying alone.

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

i study alone and i'm having difficulties with these issues, please help me!

Questions:

1. Determine which type of central grid is from its curves.
   $x ^ 2 / a ^ 2 + y ^ 2 / b ^ 2 - z ^ 2 / c ^ 2 = -1$
2. Prove that rotations in $R ^ 2$ commute.
   $R_a * R_b = R_b * R_a$
3. Prove that rotations in $R^3$ do not commute.
4. How to transform cylindrical coordinates into Cartesian coordinates?
5. $ρ \sin ϕ = 2$
6. A surface in $R ^ 3$ is given by coordinate $(ρ, θ, ϕ)$, how to translate into Cartesian coordinates and what is this surface?

Comment: Thanks for replying, I can not answer the questions. I'll do it!

Comment: Unfortunately, I feel I had to flag this. This isn’t a site that will solve problems **for** you, and some effort or examples of your own thoughts must be shown. That way, we can help you—and others—the best we can. For more information, please read [how to ask a good question](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ). At any rate, I wish the best of luck to you, and please continue to contribute to our wonderful site!

Comment: I see again and again a discouraging of individuals that try to learn math. Why this is of topic? Did you try to study math on your own at the basic level? May be you are PHDs but not with real feeling for the public.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an attempt to answer the issues:

1. Determine which type of central grid is from its curves.
   $x ^ 2 / a ^ 2 + y ^ 2 / b ^ 2 - z ^ 2 / c ^ 2 = -1$

This is a [Two Sheeted Hyperboloid](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2%2By%5E2-z%5E2%3D-1)

2. Prove that rotations in $R ^ 2$ commute.
   $R_a * R_b = R_b * R_a$

[2D Rotation Matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#In_two_dimensions) are just orthonormal matrices or order 2x2, which in particular commute.

3. Prove that rotations in $R^3$ do not commute.

[3D Rotation Matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#In_three_dimensions) are orthonormal matrices of order 3x3, which do not commute in $R^3$ neither in general. Just provide a counterexample rotating x then y, and y then x.

4. How to transform cylindrical coordinates into cartesian coordinates?

[Cylindrical Cordinates](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CylindricalCoordinates.html) are just given by: $x=\rho \cos(\theta)$, $y=\rho \sin(\theta)$, $z=h$

5. $ρ \sin ϕ = 2$

This is simply a curve having the $\rho\sin(\theta)$ segment constant. In [polar plot coordinates](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=r%20sin%20%CF%95%20%3D%202), this is simply the line $y=2$.

6. A surface in $R ^ 3$ is given by coordinate $(ρ, θ, ϕ)$, how to translate into cartesian coordinates and what is this surface?

[Spherical Coordinates](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCoordinates.html) into cartesian are doing by $x=r\cos(\theta)\sin(\phi)$,$y=r\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi)$,$z=r\cos(\phi)$ (which is not the selection i prefer, but the explained in Wolfram Alpha).

Without the actual coordinates, this object can be anything.

Comment: Many thanks for the explanation! I made great progress with them.